# Is there a simpler way to take a substring of an char array and convert it to a long in C?

Tags: c, ntp

I am looking for a shorter/more elegant way to get an NTP timestamp from a received NTP packet. The packet is stored in an unsigned char array, buf, from the socket function recvfrom:

```
unsigned char buf[48];
recvfrom(sockfd, buf, 48, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &addr_len));
```

I am then copying the value of the 40th-43rd elements which represent a 32-bit timestamp of seconds into an unsigned long, transSec, with bitshifting like so:

```
recvPacket->transmitSec = buf[40];
recvPacket->transSec <<= 8;
recvPacket->transSec |= buf[41];
recvPacket->transSec <<= 8;
recvPacket->transSec |= buf[42];
recvPacket->transSec <<= 8;
recvPacket->transSec |= buf[43];
```

This works fine, but in the interest of learning, is there a shorter/more elegant way of doing this? I have tried memcpy:

```
memcpy(&recvPacket->transSec, &buf[40], sizeof(unsigned long));
```

And some other variations of the above, but am getting incorrect numbers. I am not particularly confident I'm using it correctly.

Comment: The bitshift method is fine and will be the most efficient. However, your issues may be due to the fact that you shift left by 8 bits and `or` with a character in `buf` -- is `buf[41-43]` guaranteed to be initialized, and if so, to what?. `memcpy` is also fine if you have sequential memory you can copy from and too. However, `memcpy` takes pointer arguments. `buf[40]` is **already** a pointer (e.g. `*(buf + 40)` ). Taking its address a second time is wrong.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes buf[41-43] is guaranteed to be initialized by the NTP server sending the packet. The bitshift method works perfectly, and I get the number I expect (an NTP timestamp of when the packet was sent). Can you suggest the correct memcpy syntax?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: given the declaration `unsigned char buf[48];`, I don't see how you can claim `buf[40]` is already a pointer.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Good to have you here Johathan, you are correct. I don't know where my mind was, too many things going on -- don't have kids...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this might be actually is an *endianness* issue. Check the wiki entry here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. In short, the byte ordering of a type isn't necessarily the same from one system to another. It looks like you're doing network communication - check out the byte order conversion family functions:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

Note that buf[40] is the first byte from the stream, and is being shifted all the way to the highest byte of the underlying type. memcpy on the other hand, will copy buf[40] into the 0-offset of transSec - effectively the byte order is reversed in your two examples.

You can check it out in your code like this, you'll declare a character pointer ( character being the smallest addressable type in c) and walk the length of the size of the type from the address you're inspecting, to the address+sizeof(type):

```
// declare a char *
char * walker;
// set it to your integer
walker = (char *)&(recvPacket->transSec);
for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned long); i++){
    // print out the bytes from memory address[0] - address[3] ( assuming 4-byte unsigned long)
    printf("%x\n", walker[i]);
}
```

You can walk buff like this too, but that's already a char buffer so, you might as well just print it. I think you'll see the byte order reversed.

Comment: This was the source of the problem. Using memcpy(&recvPacket->transSec, &buf[40], 4) and then ntohl()'ing that solved it and I should have known better :) Many thanks.

Comment: This needs to be `unsigned char *`, not `char *`. The latter may point to a signed type in which case you would get wrong values.